# Can't figure out why my if statement isn't working: ( if array[i] << average)

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, average

I'm supposed to be making a program to take 5 ages, calculate the average, then display how many of the ages are above the average and how many are below. Easy, I thought. 
However, for some reason, no matter what I do, the if statement to check if the current ages[] element is less than the average always holds true and the if statement to check if the current ages[] element is more than the average always hold false, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.
Maybe it's because it's 3:30am here and my brain has gone to mush.

I have tried adding in a variable called age = ages[j] for every iteration.
I have also tried swapping around the above and below if statements however that also doesn't change anything.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main() {
    int ages[5];
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;
    int above = 0;
    int below = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Enter an age.";
        cin >> ages[i];
        cout << ages[i];
        total += ages[i];
    }
    average = total / 5;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (ages[j] >> average) {
            cout << ages[j];
            above++;
        }
        else if (ages[j] << average) {
            cout << average;
            cout << ages[j];
            below++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The average age is " << average << "." << endl;
    cout << above << " ages are above the average age." << endl;
    cout << below << " ages are below the average age." << endl;
}
```

I expect the output of 
"The average age is (average)"
"x ages are above the average age."
"y ages are above the average age"

Instead I get:
"The average age is (average)"
"0 ages are above the average age."
"5 ages are below the average age."

Comment: Don't you mean `ages[j] < average`? The `<<` operator is a bit-shifting operator and should evaluate to `true` in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You are using bitshifts instead of greater-than/less-than

```
if (ages[j] > average)
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much, it was driving me mad!